# Mark CheckBox depending on a field from sql

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Hello everyone I have the following case if you can help me, I have a DataGridView with data loaded from my `Contacts` table of my SQL Server database.

[image]

**and this is my structure of my table in sql**

[image]

This is my code to show the data in the c # form I am working in nlayers: layer_Data

```
public DataTable Contactos_ClieProvs(String basesita, String codClie)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    try
    {
        SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(conexion.CargarBase(basesita));
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("execute CONTACTOS  @tipo=13,@IdClieProv='" + codClie + "'", cnn);
        //cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        try
        {
            if (cnn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                cnn.Open();
            }
            else
            {
                cnn.Close();
                cnn.Open();
            }
            da.Fill(dt);
        }
        catch (SqlException ex) { throw ex; }
        finally
        {
            cnn.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException ex1) { throw ex1; }
    return dt;
}
```

and this is my method created to display the information in the DataGridView in the load event:

```
public void cargardatos()
{
    dt = negCli.DatosContacto(MODULOS.Globales.Base, txtcod.Text.Trim());
    bs.DataSource = dt;
    bs.AddingNew += bs_AddingNew;
    dt.RowDeleting += dt_RowDeleting;
    this.dgvcontactos.DataSource = bs;
    return;
}

private void frmContactos_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try {
        cargardatos();
        doWork.ValueType = typeof(bool);
        doWork.Name = "chbk";
        doWork.HeaderText = "Para Cobranzas";
        doWork.FalseValue = "0";
        doWork.TrueValue = "1";
        dgvcontactos.Columns.Insert(0, doWork);
    }
    catch (SqlException ex1) { MessageBox.Show(ex1.Message, "MENSAJE", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation); }
    catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "MENSAJE", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error); }
   
}
```

What I want is that the CHECKBOX is marked according to the value of the column "TO LOAD" IF IT IS 1 = FRAME and if it is 0 = it should not be marked.

So far I have not been able to achieve this functionality.

[image]

Comment: Add the DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn before you set the DataSource of your DGV. Set its `DataPropertyName` to the name of the db Column it will be bound to. Its `ValueType`  must match the Type of the db Column (handle it if it's text, not if it's a boolean, not necessary) -- You also need to dispose of all disposable objects you create, as the Connection, Command and DataAdapter (if you - as it appears - don't store this object to update your database). If an object provides a `Dispose()` method, you need to call it, or declare the object with a `using` statement (better).

Comment: Looking at the SQL table, the `para_cobranza` field already exist in the table and it looks like a Boolean field. There should be NO need to “add” the check box column, the grid will automatically create the check box column for you when you set that table as a data source. For combo boxes YOU DO need to add the column to the grid. This is not so for a check box column. The grid will auto map Boolean columns to a check box column.

Comment: Of course, that field "for collection" is of the numeric type, but it is the user who registers whether this contact is for collection or not, what I am trying to understand is that when loading the information from the table if the field for collection is in 1 that the check is marked implying that the user is for collection.

Comment: If the column in the DB is an `int`, then if you add the check box column as you have will work, however you are not following @Jimi instructions to set the columns `DataPropertyName`. Something like… `doWork.DataPropertyName = “para_cobranza”;` … in my test, even if the column type is an `int` in the DB, then when that column is mapped to the grids check box column you created…it will still work. Bear in mind zero (0) = false and any other number is going to evaluate to true.

Comment: What @jimmy says is true in this case, the checkbox column is being created internally without the design, is it necessary to create it with the design? Please give me an example if it would help me a lot to complete the idea

Comment: I do not understand what you mean in relation to the check box column. I am assuming that for some reason, the “name” of the combo box column control is `doWork`? My assumption is based on the code in the forms load event as posted… `doWork.Name = “chbk”;`, `doWork.HeaderText = “Para Cobrnzas”;` etc… so add the line as I previously posted to that code… `doWork.DataPropertyName = “para_cobranza”;`

Comment: I have added the following line
"doWork.DataPropertyName =" para_cobranza";

but this does not perform any action that could be happening?

Comment: The extra space in front of “para_cobranza” will cause this to fail. No error will be thrown, but the column will be empty. The other issue is that you need to add the column BEFORE you add the data source to the grid. Your current displayed code is adding the grids data source FIRST, then it adds the column. This will simply add a duplicate column. You should move the line of code… `cargardatos();` to execute AFTER the column has been inserted.